# Core data use to write data in memory not on disk in iOS development

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I want to use core data to store data which I am getting from APIs, and this data is for banking so need to be more cautious. Actually I am newbie in Core data so I am bit confuse about my clients requirements, following are requirements and question.

- Client mentioned in email that "We will need to keep everything in memory (never write to disk)", so what is usage of coredata?
- "We would only use a single store of type NSInMemoryStoreType; i.e. never use Sqlite or any other mechanism that writes to disk". is This the way we can achieve to store in memory?

As cleint mentioned in Note that "This is a requirement of the bank - because we will be parsing sensitive customer data we can not ever write it to disk"

Kindly give me suggestion or any reference link for how to achieve this target. Looking for response.
Thanks.

Comment: You could use the on disk encryption feature for the Core Data files that you write to disk. No need to keep everything in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set PersistentStore with NSInMemoryStoreType, and then data will be only stored in memory, not disk-based persistent store such as SQLite. The more details visit https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW3